# Visual Studio 2010 Setup Dual Runtime DLLs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer

I've got a `VS 2010 Setup Project` that deploys a couple applications, and also VS item/project templates, which allow developers to create projects that plug-in to the applications.

The item/project templates support both `.Net 3.5` and `.Net 4.0`, mainly because the service component of the application runs in `.Net 4.0`, while the client component of the application runs in `SharePoint 2007/2010`.

To get this going, I've added a conditional compilation symbol so that one project builds the same code in 35 while another project builds the same code in `4.0`.  If the assembly needs to be deployed to the GAC, how can I add both to the Global Assembly Cache folder in the VS Setup project, so that the 3.5 version of the DLL goes to C:\Windows\assembly, while the 40 version of the DLL goes to C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly?

Currently adding both versions of the DLL (same output name) results in a warning, which then upon attempting installation causes an installer error `... Verify that you have access to that directory".`

Comment: Which installer tool are you using?

Comment: The VS 2010 Setup Project, OOTB with Visual Studio

Comment: You are aware that the Setup Project feature within Visual Studdio was so bad ( it has a ton of bugs ) that they simply dropped it in the current version of Visual Studio.  I suggest you look at alternatives because your ability to customize the install will be nearly nill.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen a great deal of comments like that, but for the most part it has done the job.  I'll possibly consider some of the free-ish ones out there.

Comment: I've since switched entirely to WIX and have not looked back :)